How to reference a string resource in Kotlin activity, not XML
In Android Studio, I made a new Kotlin activity and a .xml file to go along with it. I know in the xml file having hardcoded text is bad, and you should use this answer to reference a string resource instead. I have code in my Kotlin activity that checks if a user submitted a proper email, and gives an error message if it is not valid. I don't want to hardcode the error message, so I try to reference a string resource like before, but it doesn't work. How do I reference the strings in strings.xml in a Kotlin activity, not another .xml file?
My Kotlin code looks like this, where EmailNotValid is an entry in strings.xml:
 fun signup(){
        val email = binding.emailInput.text.toString()

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
        {
            binding.emailInput.setError(@string/EmailNotValid)
            return;
        }

Thank you all!

From an activity or using a Context, you can use resources.getString(R.string.your_string_name).
You can also use getString(R.string.your_string_name).
In your case:
     fun signup(){
            val email = binding.emailInput.text.toString()
    
            if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
            {
                // Get string
                val emailErrorMessage = getString(R.string.EmailNotValid)
    
                // Use it
                binding.emailInput.setError(emailErrorMessage)
                return;
    
               

 }


You can use this method:
val myString = getString(R.string.my_string_resource)

And as an example in res/values/strings.xml:
<string name="my_string_resource">Hello, World!</string>

And you can access it in the activity:
val myString = getString(R.string.my_string_resource)

This retrieves the string resource identified by R.string.my_string_resource and assigns it to the variable myString.
